# Graus de liberdade anova R

Tags: r, anova

Estou tentando rodar uma one-way ANOVA básica no R.

```
library(drc)
data=S.alba
aov(DryMatter~Dose,data=S.alba)
```

Entretanto, existem 7 tratamentos nesses dados. Portanto, DF (degree of freedom) ou Graus de liberdade dos tratamentos deveria ser 7-1 = 6, mas o R  me apresenta a DF como 1. Não entendi o que se passa. Alguém pode me esclarecer essa duvida?

```
> aov(DryMatter~Dose,data=S.alba)
Call:
   aov(formula = DryMatter ~ Dose, data = S.alba)

Terms:
                    Dose Residuals
Sum of Squares  65.62088  75.12662
Deg. of Freedom        1        66

Residual standard error: 1.066903
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A coluna Dose é um valor numérico do tipo `int`, não um fator:

```
dados <- S.alba
str(dados)
'data.frame':   68 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Dose     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 10 ...
 $ Herbicide: Factor w/ 2 levels "Bentazone","Glyphosate": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ DryMatter: num  4.7 4.6 4.1 4.4 3.2 3 3.8 3.9 3.8 3.8 ...
```

Assim, o R não vai entender que a variável explicativa é um fator. Converta a coluna `Dose`, de modo que ela vire uma variável categórica:

```
dados$Dose <- as.factor(dados$Dose)
str(dados)
'data.frame':   68 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Dose     : Factor w/ 8 levels "0","10","20",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Herbicide: Factor w/ 2 levels "Bentazone","Glyphosate": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ DryMatter: num  4.7 4.6 4.1 4.4 3.2 3 3.8 3.9 3.8 3.8 ...
```

Além disso, apenas o comando `aov` não vai te dar a tabela ANOVA que tu deseja. Tu deve primeiro ajustar um modelo com a função `aov` e depois pedir o `summary` dele:

```
ajuste <- aov(DryMatter~Dose, data=dados)
summary(ajuste)

            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
Dose         7 121.17  17.310   53.04 <2e-16 ***
Residuals   60  19.58   0.326                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```